# Inner Join on Dynamic Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I have looked through the feeds to see if there is an answer to this but have not had any luck. I want to join the results of this output to another table using an INNER JOIN. I have tried to do this how I know best but keep getting an error. Is there a simple piece of code for this to work?

I have seen on other posts some suggest that you populate the results of this query into a temp table and then join from that outside of the @SQL statement but again I have not had any luck creating a temp table within this syntax.

```
  SELECT @Table_Name = Result_ID FROM #TmpResults
  SET @SQL = 'SELECT * From [SERVER].[DATABASE].[dbo].'+@Table_Name
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you continue your SQL statement in the variable you create.

```
SELECT @Table_Name = Result_ID FROM #TmpResults
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * From [SERVER].[DATABASE].[dbo].'+ @Table_Name + ' INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 ON dbo.Table2.Id = ' + @Table_Name + '.Table2Id'
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot save them to a temp table because it is not visible to SQL beyond the dynamic SQL query when you execute it.

You can however save to a permanent table.

```
SELECT @Table_Name = Result_ID FROM #TmpResults
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * INTO NewTable From [SERVER].[DATABASE].[dbo].'+@Table_Name
```